# Confused in making a C# Login Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, login-control

I need help in creating a simple login control using 2 custom text boxes to allow users to log into a profile of their own.
I have created the profile page. But I'm kind of clueless on how to write the code behind the

```
> btnLogin
```

I have a register page which allows me perfectly to save the details onto a SQL database table. I know this must be a simple set of code but I'm probably making it too complicated.
as an example

my text box Variables are

```
txtUserName

txtPassword
```

My SQL table name is UserDetails which includes the Username and password and few other fields which is irrelevant to the login activity.

............
Response redirect page I want the User to go to is `ProfileOfUser.aspx` based on UserIds.
something similar to this,

```
Response.Redirect("ProfileOfUser.aspx?Id=" + Session["UserId"].ToString());
```

would be really appreciative if anyone can help me figure this out :)

Comment: so... whats your question

Comment: Are you doing that in MVC platform? If yes, you can just create a new MVT project and select the internet/intranet project template. There are some scaffolding code there, which includes the authentication code you can read. I guess you can get some reference from there even you are doing that in web form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use ASP.NET login control?
[ASP.NET Login Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms178329%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I want to use a custom design I have created, Thats why I'm not using the ASP.NET Login control

Comment: Managed to manipulate the asp.login control in the design layout i wanted :) thanks for the help everyone